# IntelliJ application shortcut not found

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop

I have installed [IntelliJ IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

But i am not able to see the Icon or shortcut to open the IDE.

I have installed the license version that i got in my email.

I have tried to search the installed location and found inside `Program Files`

But i haven't find the application shortcut.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the shortcut of `Batch` file inside below location.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\ideaIU-2017.1.6.win\bin

[image]

You can add icon to this file from properties.